# call Equal method of Expression

Tags: c#, lambda, expression

when I run this code

```
Expression left = Expression.Constant(10, typeof(int));
Expression right = Expression.Constant(10,typeof(int));

var method10 = typeof(Expression).GetMethod("Equal", new[] { typeof(Expression), typeof(Expression) });
Expression exp = Expression.Call(method10,left,right);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(exp);
var compiled = lambda.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
```

I get the below error

Additional information: Expression of type `'System.Int32'` cannot be used for parameter of type `'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression'` of method `'System.Linq.Expressions.BinaryExpression Equal(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression)'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need reflection, unless I'm missing something:

```
Expression left = Expression.Constant(10, typeof(int));
Expression right = Expression.Constant(10,typeof(int));
Expression exp = Expression.Equal(left, right);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(exp);
```

Clearly you could manually call the `int.Equals(int)` method...

```
var method10 = left.Type.GetMethod("Equals", new[] { right.Type });
Expression exp = Expression.Call(left, method10, right);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(exp);
```

but note that there is a subtle difference: `Expression.Equal` will use the `==` operator, while the other code will use the `Equals` method.

If you really want to build an expression from a string:

```
string methodName = "Equal";
MethodInfo method10 = typeof(Expression).GetMethod(methodName, new[] { typeof(Expression), typeof(Expression) });
Expression exp = (Expression)method10.Invoke(null, new object[] { left, right });
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(exp);
```

or

```
ExpressionType type = (ExpressionType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ExpressionType), methodName);
var exp = Expression.MakeBinary(type, left, right);
```

using the `Enum.Parse`

Comment: you know , I want to have a method that has 3 inputs .  first :a string such as  GreaterThan, GreaterThanOrEqual , Equal , NotEqual etc .Second : int or string , third : int or string . and call the first method which is a string on 2 other arguments .

Comment: @unosbaghaii Then use the Ondrej method and use a the parameter the `ExpressionType.Equal`

Comment: i want to give this "ExpressionType.Equal" dynamically , from a string

Comment: @unosbaghaii See it now

Answer (score 3):

I solved it . thanks guys

```
Expression left = Expression.Constant(10, typeof(int));
Expression right = Expression.Constant(10, typeof(int));
ExpressionType expressionType;
var tryParseRes = ExpressionType.TryParse("NotEqual", out expressionType);
var exp = Expression.MakeBinary(expressionType, left, right);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(exp);
var compiled = lambda.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
if ((bool)compiled == false)
    areEventCondiotionsPassed = false;
```

Comment: You are right. It is the Visual Studio that doesn't show it.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var exp = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, left, right);
```

instead of

```
var method10 = typeof(Expression).GetMethod("Equal", new[] { typeof(Expression), typeof(Expression) });
Expression exp = Expression.Call(method10,left,right);
```

Comment: thanks a lot . it works . but I want something to be dynamic to be able to call any methods such as Equal, NotEqual etc. and keep my code just in 5 to 10 lines